# Unexpected empty sequence in linq to sql result

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a simple query that deletes an entry from a table

```
        CB_User_Schedule deleted = (from x in db.CB_User_Schedules
                                    where x.ScheduleID == CurrentScheduleID
                                    select x).Single();
        db.CB_User_Schedules.DeleteOnSubmit(deleted);
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

However, the first statement returns `Sequence contains no elements`. I can see that when it executes the value of CurrentScheduleID is in fact a number and when I directly execute `select * from CB_UserSchedules where ScheduleID = 3` it does return a row. So why is my statement not finding that row in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the emitted SQL with the built-in LINQ-to-SQL logging (hook up a TextWriter to the Log property on your DataContext) or SQL profiler. More than likely you've got a datatype mismatch or key issue in your DBML (ie, something doesn't match reality in the DB and the mapper is barfing on it). We run a very large and complex site almost exclusively on L2S, and these kinds of issues are almost always related to broken DBML.

Comment: Its interesting though because when I query the same table and just try and pull all of the rows that row is in that result set. But I will look into that!